# SFTP Request with Clojure and clj-ssh using simple username and password

Tags: ssh, clojure, sftp

I'm getting

```
JSchException Auth fail  com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect (Session.java:512)
```

when attemping to use the `sftp` function in `clj-ssh.cli` -- e.g.,

```
(sftp "mysite.org" :username "foo" :password "bar" :get "/foo.txt" "foo.txt")
```

I've confirmed the user and pass are correct. What am I missing? (Note that I'm using a simple user/pass, no keys involved here.)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the order matters.

```
(sftp "mysite.org" :get "/foo.txt" "foo.txt" :username "foo" :password "bar")
```

More info: https://crossclj.info/fun/clj-ssh.cli/sftp.html